# Android: NullPointer Exception on recreating the alarm on OS Bootup?

Tags: android, notifications, android-ndk, system, android-manifest

I am going to create the recreat the alarm while Android OS bootup.

that why i am using this code in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".RecreateTwoMonthAlarm" >         
        <intent-filter>             
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />         
        </intent-filter>     
    </receiver>
```

Well, it runs perfect. but every time while i bootup my device, i got NullPointer Exception.

Here is my code onReceive method:

//I am going to inatialize myPrefs here

```
myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

// but i got symtax error like: MODE_WORLD_READABLE cannot be resolved to a variable

```
Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, myPrefs.getInt("hour", 00), myPrefs.getInt("minute", 00), 0); // here i got exception
            if(!(calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis()<=currentTime)){
                AM_2M_GST_1 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                intent.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 20th June 2011.");
                PI_2M_GST_1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AM_2M_GST_1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), PI_2M_GST_1);
            }

            // for the GST 19 August 2011
            Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17,myPrefs.getInt("hour", 00), myPrefs.getInt("minute", 00), 0);
            if(!(calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis()<=currentTime)){
                AM_2M_GST_2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                in2.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 19th August 2011.");
                PI_2M_GST_2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, in2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AM_2M_GST_2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_2);
            }
```

i think it is because i am using the shared preference data to set alarm at specific time. Isen't it ??

am i not able to set the Shared Preference Data in to Bootup of Device or why i got that exception ??

Error Log:

```
    02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.project.TaxToolbox.RecreateTwoMonthAlarm: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at com.project.TaxToolbox.RecreateTwoMonthAlarm.onReceive(RecreateTwoMonthAlarm.java:46)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
02-03 12:19:27.612: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(246):     ... 10 more
```

Please help me for that.

Thanks.

Comment: getting NullPointer Exception? where is log?

Comment: I have commented the line where i got that exception. Anyway let me put the log while second time i got. wait for the updation a i am working on another project.

Comment: where does myPrefs get initiated? from this perspective I'd expect it to be NULL

Comment: Yes may be its true. right now i am not goint to initialize. And if i am going to initialize it before my code start i got syntex error.

Comment: Post more code. Post the function that sets your myPrefs.

Comment: I am setting myPrefs from the Activity while the application is running. I think it is just because I am not initializing it. So please give me some code that initialize myPrefs for my code as if i am going to initialize it, it gives me syntax error.

Comment: @Spidy: Please now see updated question with initializing of the myPrefs. but i m not successful in it. Please help me for that.

Comment: Try changing it to Context.WORLD_MODE_READABLE

Comment: @Spidy : I have try it. But stil same syntax error.

Comment: @Spidy: it works. Please put answer So i select it as accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Context.WORLD_MODE_READABLE, depending on where you are calling this piece of code, it might not think that "this" is type Context (for example inside an anonymous function or inner class)